# Hello, my name is Katey and I am here?

Tags: discussion, editing

My name is Katey and I work for Stack Exchange as a member of the newish CHAOS team!

Over the next few days, I will be scuttling around and editing entries and titles for clarity. CHAOS has a set of guidelines to follow when improving questions, but we aren't out to step on anyone's toes, but I am also building up my rep here and trying to learn as much about this topic (which I have basic familiarity with but am not an expert in by any stretch). In general, I am just revising for spelling, grammar, and overall clarity. If I edit your question (or a question you've already edited) and you don't agree with the changes I've made, feel free to roll them back. I am learning from you all!

I won't be editing questions here in meta, but I will be dropping in to say hi and see what's going on - so feel free to let me know if you have any questions, concerns or complaints. I want to get to know the community here, and find out what CHAOS can do for this community.

You can follow me on twitter @KateyCHAOS, so feel free to do that so I can follow you back! You can also follow the whole team on our StackHQ tumblr: http://stackexchange.tumblr.com/ Thanks everyone.

Comment: Welcome and good luck Katey :)

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason the Ψ isn't showing up on this account, sorry! Oh noes!

Comment: You seem unsure as to whether or not you're really here. Meta- *physical!*

Comment: Badum-psh! Thanks for checking up on the temp-mod thing, I was informed this AM after posting, so I edited my post without explaining.

Comment: Hi @Katey, I'm @rahul! We should chat sometime (google hangout? with patrick and some others?) about your plans for UX and how we can work together. Welcome!

Comment: Sounds great! I am really looking to the users for input, and have just started researching some of the UX conferences coming up in 2012, including the SXSXi in March.

Comment: *"editing entries and titles for clarity."* Great stuff! I do a bit of that type of editing, and it's always nice to see others doing some to make questions and answers easier to understand. Hope you're better at English than I am though - I just speak it, as opposed to study it. ;)

Comment: @KateyΨ You should check out aneventapart.com - their next conference is in late October in DC (I'm attending), but they are held 5-6 times per year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer you question, your name is Katey, K-A-T-E-Y.